# App crashes in TestFlight but not in Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crash, expo

I uploaded my App to App Store Connect and tried to launch it in TestFlight, but it crashes immediately.

I tried to start the app in -.-no-dev --minify mode, and I got this error message in console:

```
DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue? It looks like the app is missing access to http_parser - or some other access-issue?

**Crash Log:**

```
Incident Identifier: 388E2322-6BCE-4415-9F4A-CB6C4A079E10
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,2
Process:             Yukigassen [52962]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/518A710D-C7E7-49E8-88E0-    5F773B8A20C5/Yukigassen.app/Yukigassen
Identifier:          com.eakz.Yukigassen
Version:             1.0.0 (2)
AppStoreTools:       14A305
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,2:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.eakz.Yukigassen [2191]

Date/Time:           2022-09-08 09:37:35.7056 +0200
Launch Time:         2022-09-08 09:37:33.9243 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6.1 (19G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.04.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  6

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x19da19288 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b6749744 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   Yukigassen                      0x1020b2af4 -[EXUpdatesAppController throwException:] + 24 (EXUpdatesAppController.m:422)
3   Yukigassen                      0x1020c6a44 -[EXUpdatesErrorRecovery _crash] + 984 (EXUpdatesErrorRecovery.m:222)
4   Yukigassen                      0x1020c60f8 -[EXUpdatesErrorRecovery _runNextTask] + 148 (EXUpdatesErrorRecovery.m:0)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x19d67ee6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x19d680a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x19d688124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x19d688c80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x19d693500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x20ebd50bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x20ebd4e5c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b64a0 mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d986d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d98b1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d99ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b9b0a374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0312b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a0094090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
8   Yukigassen                      0x0000000102083f64 main + 88 (main.m:7)
9   dyld                            0x0000000102621da4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e54 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e54 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e54 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b64a0 mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d986d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d98b1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d99ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019f191444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019f1d2e0c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a028ccc4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x000000019f1e141c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e54 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54bcb38 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdb3bc pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a8b2b524 abort + 168 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b6854b7c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b68449c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b674fc68 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b6853f18 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b6853eb4 std::terminate() + 64 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019d680a44 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019d688124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019d688c80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019d693500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd50bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e5c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b64a0 mach_msg_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d986d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d98b1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019d99ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Yukigassen                      0x00000001021a9e5c +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 264 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:378)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019f1e141c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8cce0b8 scavenger_thread_main + 1088 (pas_scavenger.c:135)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d54b6f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebdc298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c2cc20 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf1c18 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 308 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8bf20a0 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c4ddc4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001a8c500d0 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd59ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020ebd4e68 thread_start + 8 (:-1)


Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001b68580f5   x5: 0x000000016e0c6430   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000b00
    x8: 0xce04e43fe3e13e6c   x9: 0xce04e43e8ded4e6c  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x000000019dd56a9f  x14: 0x00000001b685811b  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016e0c7000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000002e03  x21: 0x000000016e0c70e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016e0c70e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000028391f668  x26: 0x0000000000000114  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000028020cd00   fp: 0x000000016e0c63a0   lr: 0x000000020ebdb3bc
    sp: 0x000000016e0c6380   pc: 0x00000001d54bcb38 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x10207c000 - 0x102373fff Yukigassen arm64  <2eb0689581ac3d53860046ace589224a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/518A710D-C7E7-49E8-88E0-        5F773B8A20C5/Yukigassen.app/Yukigassen
0x102608000 - 0x10265ffff dyld arm64e  <66e1fb2668f8379ba052eb8b8291b5e1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x19d67d000 - 0x19d6c2fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <e3ea4f635d11342aaf199f58dbc8e259> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x19d980000 - 0x19ddd5fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <6b22dd8135853be6bc77ba19810ec0f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x19f178000 - 0x19f482fff Foundation arm64e  <ee1abaf23d7137fb906715aa79528619> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x19fdfe000 - 0x1a169bfff UIKitCore arm64e  <137a95aada6d332cbc01e13bb9b6e317> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1a8b0b000 - 0x1a8b8afff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <86a1a24ace353769ba6960f28353281e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a8be3000 - 0x1aa067fff JavaScriptCore arm64e  <e76b377fc862395a9439d12b09a59e07> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1b6733000 - 0x1b676ffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <f6368be9109b3405b282624040529afd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1b6843000 - 0x1b685afff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <d00067b20a7a3cb9b4d407b160da261b> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1b9b09000 - 0x1b9b11fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <a094e7b51d4037c5902756d86988ec4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1d54b5000 - 0x1d54eafff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <1fb39303587b320eaeb8e51a54c8a4a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x20ebd4000 - 0x20ebdffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <adc41700002e3a2bb4a1eb5fbf575770> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
yarn remove @prisma/cli
yarn add prisma --dev

yarn upgrade @prisma/client
```